# Passing a list to a controller action using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I currently store the model, which is a list of a model which contains different data such as `id, name` etc, in a `JSON` object. I pass this model back to a controller action. The problem is the `List` contains the correct amount but all the data with the model are null. Below is my code:

Model:

```
#region Client Employees
public class EmployeesModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Firm { get; set; }
    public double? Bonus { get; set; }
    public double? Salary { get; set; }
    public double? Compensation { get; set; }
}

public class ViewEmployeesModel
{
    public List<EmployeesModel> employees { get; set; }
}
#endregion
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var clients = DeepfieldClient.GetAllClientEmployees();
        ViewEmployeesModel employees = new ViewEmployeesModel
        {
            employees = clients
        };
        return View(employees);
    }

    public JsonResult GetClients(List<EmployeesModel> model)
    {
        //Do something with the clients in the model
        return Json(false);
    }
```

Js:

```
   GetClientData: function () 
   {       
    $("#GetDataBtn").on("click", function () {
        var searchCriteria = $(".dataSelectOptions").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/GetClients",
            data: { model: model },
            success: function (response) {
                GetData.FillTable(response);
            }
        });
    });
},
```

model is stored in the view as:

```
var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.employees))
```

Any ideas as why i will be retrieving the correct amount but null values?

Comment: Can you edit the post to include a sample of what `model` looks like when written into page, that could give a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JSON.stringify()` your `data` before you send it. And also decorate your controller action method with `[HttpPost]`. `contentType: "application/json"` the type of data you're sending to the server and `dataType: "json"` the data type you're expecting to get back.

Try this:

```
@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $("button").click(function(){
            var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.employees));

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetClients","Customers")",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(model)
            })
            .done(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        });


    });


</script>

}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetClients(List<EmployeesModel> model)
{
    //Do something with the clients in the model
    return Json(false);
}
```

Comment: I was receiving a post error and saw that the JSON was too big to serialize. So this helped:<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" /> within the appsettings in the config file. Thank you very much it's working now

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't know what `model` is, try:

```
data: { model: '@model' },
```

The data is in Razor not JavaScript.

Comment: But would that ajax call need to be within the view? or can i call it from an external js file and still access '@model'?